# Background image resize height

Tags: html, css

I am trying set a background image in a `div` and have it resize with the browser. The width works fine, but I can't get the height to stretch or shrink.

Using `content:url` works exactly how I want it to but it only works with Chrome.

```
.bg01 {
   content:url('images/bg.jpg');
   max-width:100%;
}
```

I have tried the following, the width is fine but the height doent change

```
.bg01 {
   background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   width:750px;
   height: 240px;
   background-size:contain;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the width and height of the div to `100vw` and `100vh`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like `background-size: cover` is what you want, not contain.

---

**EDIT**: after looking at your comments I think I understand what you're after better. Is there a reason you have to do it with CSS only? Because the `content: url(...)` thing is essentially the same as adding the image to the markup, so you can achieve the exact same thing with this:

```css
/* using content: url(...) */

.content-url {
  content: url('https://static.magento.com/sites/default/files8/styles/column_4/public/WEB-2612_Listing_Images_Events_r1v1_b_16.jpg?itok=cVv6YfZf');
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* using an img tag */

.markup > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>using content: url(...):</p>
<div class="content-url"></div>

<br><br>

<p>using an img tag:</p>
<div class="markup">
  <img src="https://static.magento.com/sites/default/files8/styles/column_4/public/WEB-2612_Listing_Images_Events_r1v1_b_16.jpg?itok=cVv6YfZf" alt="">
</div>
```

Also, support for `content: url()` is actually pretty decent, including the most recent versions of firefox, safari and even edge and ie11: https://caniuse.com/#search=content%3A%20url

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using 'cover.' I can't remember using anything other than cover in 95% of cases. Basically - it's always cover - unless it's a repeating background pattern.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; /* they don't know how tall they are... */
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/2000x2000');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6cyz1mLk/ examples other than on body

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried cover but I still cant get it working as I want. Basically I want the height to be relative to the width when its resized

Comment: You might have a messy mental model of how this works. I'm not sure what you want is possible.

Comment: `.bg01 {
       content:url('images/bg.jpg');
       max-width:100%;
    }`

Works exactly how I want but it only works in chrome

Comment: This sets a max width of 100%. But the element knows nothing about its height.

Comment: You're not alone. Everyone goes through this "why can't it just be the aspect ration I want... " / well... because of lots of reasons. But that's just part of learning. : )

Comment: Thanks again, it would be great if this worked with firefox, edge etc https://jsfiddle.net/p537v0hj/

Comment: according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=content%3A%20url), it should work on all of those, in the current versions.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/2000x1024");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: ok. am so sorry about that. thanks for your suggestion to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code hope it will work for what you want, for getting same result as content:"", you have to set aspect ratio of background div by change the padding value same as the actual image aspect ratio. :)

```css
.content-box { margin-bottom: 10px;; content: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg); width: 100%;}
.bg-box { background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg) no-repeat top left / 100% auto;}
.bg-box::after { content: ""; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; padding-top: 100%; display: block;}
```

```html
<html>
    <head><title>bg image same as content css</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="content-box"></div>
    <div class="bg-box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```